# VBA to detect row number in REAL TIME

Tags: vba, excel

I have a piece of VBA code to alternate row color in a specific range. But it only runs once when the excel file is open.

Currently I am using a button to run the VBA when I need to renew the alternate color. Is there any way the VBA can detect the change in row in REAL TIME?

Thanks in advance for your help

Jim

Comment: Sure. Take a look at the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194470.aspx

Comment: You can use conditional formatting for this, or format your data as a Table and select a style with alternating row colors.

Comment: I have been googling the problem for a while but in vein. I believe I used the wrong search words. Thans Doug for the reference.

Comment: I know the two ways you mentioned. But not exactly what I am looking for. But thanks for pointing it out, Tim.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a function called Worksheet_Change, which is called any time a cell will change. Try the following code (paste it in the VBA-Editor of the worksheet)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("A1:C10")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

        ' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been 
        ' changed.
        ' Place your code here.
        MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I started a new module and pasted your code in VBA editor. When I run it, excel kept prompting me to name the marco and save it. But I believe it was already named (Worksheet_Change). I am using excel 2007. Is it the version issue or do I miss anything?

Comment: Well, I think I know the problem. I need to change the two dropdown menu about the vba editor area to "worksheet" & "selection Change".

Comment: Another problem pops up. "worksheet-change" will color the cell whenever I click the cell in range, no matter it is filled or empty. Do I have to put a checking mechanism in the code to see if cells in range are empty or not? Is there a better a to do it?